# How do I save an Int array in Swift using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

This is an array:

```
var myArray = [1]
```

It contains `Int` values.

This is how I save an array in `NSUserDefaults`. This code seems to be working fine:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myArray, forKey: "myArray")
```

This is how I load an array:

```
myArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myArray")
```

The code above, though, retrieves an error. Why?

Comment: What error do you get? A compiler error? Runtime error? An exact description of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: I was getting a compiler error. I don't remember what the error was exactly saying because Dániel's answer fixed partially my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to assign an `AnyObject?` to an array of `Int`s, beacuse
`objectForKey` returns `AnyObject?`, so you should cast it to array this way:

```
myArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myArray") as [Int]
```

If there are no values saved before, it could return nil, so you could check for it with:

```
if let temp = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myArray") as? [Int] {
    myArray = temp
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I am getting this error: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. If I comment out your code, though, everything seems to be working fine. What could this be due to? Thanks!

Comment: Should I use `objectForKey` or `arrayForKey `? Please note I saved it using `setObject `.

Comment: both would work with a conditional cast to look more concise I prefer the array for key. In case of [String] you can use stringArrayForKey and no need to use conditional cast

Answer (score 9):

You should use `if let` to unwrap your optional value and also a conditional cast. By the way you should also use `arrayForKey` as follow:

```
if let loadedArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myArray") as? [Int] {
    print(loadedArray)
}
```

Or use the nil coalescing operator `??`:

```
let loadedArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myArray") as? [Int] ?? []
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4:**

```
myArray : [Int] = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myArray") as! [Int]
```