# Check if array contains element in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to check if array `categories` contain number 1 as `Int` since `categories = [Int]()` for example `categories = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

I have tried  the below code which gives me error `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Int'`

```
if categories.contains (where: {$0 == 1}) {
    // 1 is found
}
```

also tried it without the where and brackets as below which gives me the same error

```
if categories.contains { $0 == 1 } {
    // 1 is found
}
```

I tried using just the element as below which gives me error `Missing argument label 'where:' in call`

```
if categories.contains(1) {
    // 1 is found
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How did you declare the categories array?

Comment: Your categories declaration it is not a valid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments made me check the declaration of the array and the problem was that was declared as `[Any]` after I get it's value from the `UserDefaults`. I have checked and found the solution on [How do I save an Int array in Swift using NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197041/how-do-i-save-an-int-array-in-swift-using-nsuserdefaults)

```
// old declaration
let categories = userDefaults.array(forKey:"categories") ?? [Int]()

// new correct declaration
var categories = [Int]()
if let temp = userDefaults.array(forKey:"categories") as? [Int] {
    categories = temp
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention that you are getting your array from `UserDefaults`. If you mention first line of your code you will get the answer sooner.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like your `category` array is of type `Any`

**Ways to fix it**

- You can declare your array as an `Int` array

  ```
  var categories: [Int]
  ```

  **OR**
- You can change the following piece of code

  ```
  if categories.contains { $0 == 1 } {
      // 1 is found
  }
  ```

  to

  ```
  if categories.contains { ($0 as! Int) == 1 } {
      // 1 is found
  }
  ```

  **Note:** This method might cause your app to crash if your `category` array has an element other than of type `Int`

Comment: What is the meaning of "$0" ? @Malik

Comment: @MohamedEzzat `$0` is the first parameter passed into a closure. In this instance, when the categories array is traversed with an `contains` check, `$0` holds the value in each iteration

Answer (score 3):

it is working See my output in PlayGround

[image]

Code used:

```
var categories : [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

if categories.contains(5)
{
    print("Yes it contains")
}
else
{
    print("it do not")
}
```

and also This condition is working

```
if categories.contains (where: {$0 == 1}) {
    print("yes")
}
```

see your Array Declaration I think there is main Issue

Declaration 1 :

```
var categories = [Int]()
categories = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Declaration 2 :

```
var categories : [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: iOS Geek did mention to check the array declaration. The OP stated in the first line that the array is an `Int` array. I realise that the error states otherwise which tells me that the OP might have declared the array wrongly (exactly like iOS Geek stated). He is not assuming anything my friend.

Comment: Yes, @Malik, You are right I had mentioned to check the array declaration For that

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding error message**
`Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Int'`

Your array is not an `Int` array instead it contains `Any` so it needs typecasting before comparision. Declaration of array is also wrong use `[]` instead of `{}`. And typecast object as an int `($0 as! Int) == 1` (I'm using force casting here because I know its an Int array).

There are many ways to check if array contains any element.

**1>** Just try to get the index of element with `guard` if index is nil means array doesn't contain the element. Although you didn't declare array in right way still I'm considering it a valid array.

```
let categories: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
guard categories.index(of: 1) != nil else {
    print("Doesn't Contain")
    return
}
print("Contains")
```

**2>** Use `contains` method

```
if (categories.contains(1)) {
    print("Contains")
}
else {
    print("Doesn't Contain")
}
```

**3>** **Not Recommended for this case But still you can get this**

```
let result = categories.filter({$0 == 1})
if result.count == 0 {
   print("Doesn't Contain")
}
else {
   print("Contains")
}
```

`filter` returns an array of element which matches with condition. So that if there are multiple `1` in array so it will give you an array of all elements. And `$0` describes the object while enumerating the array.

**4>** **Not Recommended for this case**

```
let contains = categories.contains(where: {$0 == 1})
if contains {
    print("Contains")
}
else {
   print("Doesn't Contain")
}
```